# How to collapse columns and overwrite values into a single row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to collapse rows into a single line  (Last Name, First Name, ID) and at the same time, overwrite False with True any time there is a column/row that has True.  True is a system-generated flag and asks us to look more deeply into that record.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 1,2, 3,3],'LastName':['Cardinal','Cardinal', 'BlueJay', 'Robin','Robin'], 'FirstName':['Red', 'Red','Bluey', 'Round','Round'], 'French':[True, False,False,False, True], 'Flying':[False,True, True, True, False]})
```

[image]
I don't know where to start. In this case, we can't use a split-apply-combine type of thinking, since we're replacing by column and row, simultaneously.  Group-by,update, combine_first is out.  Also, there are more than 100 columns...

Desired output:
`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 2, 3],'LastName':['Cardinal', 'BlueJay', 'Robin'], 'FirstName':['Red','Bluey','Round'], 'French':[True, False, True], 'Flying':[True, True, True]})`

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `any`:

```
df.groupby(['ID','LastName','FirstName'], as_index=False).any()
```

Output:

```
   ID  LastName FirstName  French  Flying
0   1  Cardinal       Red    True    True
1   2   BlueJay     Bluey   False    True
2   3     Robin     Round    True    True
```